# what would happen when re-write URL is used in web config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

If i had the below in the web.config file, and in the code behind I was using `Request.QueryString("category")` would this still return the string or just return and empty string.

```
  <rewriter>
    <rewrite url="~/products/books.aspx?category=books" to="~/products.books.aspx" />
  </rewriter>
```

Comment: sounds like a 'give it a try' type of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the URL in the web.config file the the query string can not be used. so adding the value into a Session["id"] as an example will allow you to pass the values through, where ihave hav id u can change to a more meaninfful name.